# eslint_d: command eslint_d is not executable (make sure it's installed and on your $PATH)

Tags: eslint, neovim

[image]

`[null-ls] failed to run generator: ...site\pack\packer\start\null-ls.nvim/lua/null-ls/loop.lua:157: command eslint_d is not executable (make sure it's installed and on your $PATH)`

Recently, I installed Devaslife's nvim config. For some reason, I get this error whenever I get into the `index.jsx` file from my NextJS project. What does this error imply? How to fix it?

PS: The linter doesn't work indeed

Answer (score 4):

Are you using mason.nvim? Have you installed eslint_d from within mason itself? Try opening up the mason UI with :Mason and check if eslint_d is installed. If you didn't install it, do so with :MasonInstall eslint_d

Comment: ```npm ERR! enoent Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint_d:```

tried doing this with no success

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that eslint_d is not installed in your system and also not added to $PATH. You can try with mason or you can try with the npm package `npm install -g eslint_d`. The npm one fixed the issue for me.